# Formulário de pesquisa interna

Tags: html

Tenho um formulário de pesquisa interna no site.

```
<form  method="get" id="searchform" action="/search/">
<div>
<input type="text" value="Pesquisar..." name="q" id="s" onfocus="defaultInput(this)" onblur="clearInput(this)" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value=" " />
</div>
</form>
```

mas eu queria que quando clicado no campo `<input type="text">` o nome *Pesquisar...* desaparecer quando a pessoa digitar. Alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o atributo `placeholder` para colocar o texto que só vai aparecer quando o campo estiver vazio:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar..." name="q" id="s" onfocus="defaultInput(this)" onblur="clearInput(this)" />
```

Segundo o [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) esse atributo é suportado por todo navegador na sua versão corrente, exceto o Opera Mini (IE9 ou anterior não dá suporte).

Se você precisa que uma solução funcione em navegdores antigos, sugiro usar as próprias funções `onfocus` e `onblur` pra tratar disso - ao receber o foco, o placeholder é escondido; ao perder o foco, se o tamanho do valor for zero o placeholder é recolocado. (a alternativa seria fazer isso no `onkeyup`, de modo que somente quando o usuário **começar mesmo a digitar** o placeholder sumiria, mas não acho uma boa ideia, por vários motivos)

Você ainda teria de guardar em algum lugar a informação "o input está vazio ou não?" para decidir se o que está no `input` é um *placeholder* ou somente um **texto que por coincidência é igual ao *placeholder***... Na falta de um lugar melhor, sugiro colocar como um atributo `data-*`. Ex.:

```
<input type="text" value="Pesquisar..." data-vazio="sim" name="q" id="s" onfocus="defaultInput(this)" onblur="clearInput(this)" />
```

E é claro, manter esse atributo atualizado à medida que o usuário modifica o `input` (isso pode ser feito no próprio `onblur`, ou talvez no `onchange`).

**Atualização:** ou melhor ainda, use uma classe CSS para monitorar isso, assim além do controle que você precisa você ainda ganha "de graça" a oportunidade de alterar o estilo do input (por exemplo, fazendo a letra ficar cinza se estiver lá só o placeholder).

```
<input type="text" value="Pesquisar..." class="vazio" name="q" id="s" onfocus="defaultInput(this)" onblur="clearInput(this)" />
```

CSS:

```css
input.vazio {
    color: lightgray;
}
```

(lembrando que um elemento pode ter mais de uma classe, se necessário: `class="classe1 classe2 classe3"`)

Comment: Para solucionar a falta de suporte do IE9 ao atributo placeholder, basta usar o plugin jQuery - http://mths.be/placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso use o [`placeholder`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp).

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar..." name="q" id="s" onfocus="defaultInput(this)" onblur="clearInput(this)" />
```